# Dishwasher won't drain

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

So yesterday I noticed as the dishwasher got to the drain cycle, it was making a buzzing sound but I wasn't hearing any water go down the drain as I normally do.

I do notice that right when it starts to drain, I hear a small amount of water getting through, but not what I expect.

So far I have drained the dishwasher by hand and cleaned the screen and got any pieces of food but nothing really large seemed blocking.

I have not yet taken the pump housing out, that will be today but I'm wondering if there is something coming through, it may just mean a clog in the hose?

Not sure if someone has had the same situation, but cleaning out a clogged hose is going to be a bit easier than dealing with the pump.

Hopefully can save myself some time!

Comment: Did you try pulling the dishwasher out and checking the drain tube for clogs? On the two dishwashers I've had experience with the drain tube is slightly clear white plastic that should be apparent where a clog is, I would do that before removing any pump housings. It should be fairly easy to pull out and check, although you may have to tip the dishwasher to see the entire hose.

Comment: I found out about the issue last night and I wasn't able to get my tools to take it all out yet. That will definitely be my next step. Hoping its not the pump blown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problem. Removed the vent cap next to faucet on sink,turned dishwasher on & clog came out from the dishwasher vent..along with water! So be ready with towel.

Comment: This seems to be what my issue was. Everything running smooth again.

Answer (score 1):

The buzzing that you hear is most likely the solenoid that opens a drain valve. Dishwashers are basically constructed with similar parts, but can be placed differently. If you have the model number post it for all to see.

Meanwhile, if you remove the bottom kick plates you can see the pump. Fill the basin with water and than set the switch to just before "drain" mode. Have a flashlight at hand and listen for the "buzzing" sound while peering with the flashlight.

It may also be a clogged drain hose from the pump. In either case it may be easier to remove the washer for easier access.